# ios pass data between custom view and view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm a beginner in iOS development. I have a custom view:

```
@interface MyView : UIView {
```

In the ViewController, I add this view as a subview (would be better to do in another way, maybe in the Storyboard?):

```
MyView *myView = [[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:myFrame];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

in it, I follow the touches on screen, and I have a touchesEnded method:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // myValue is a class variable of MyView
    myValue = doSomething();
}
```

Now, how can I get the value of `myValue` in the ViewController? Maybe a listener or a callback that can be invoked inside `touchesEnded` in MyView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, you can post a *NSNotification* in *touchesEnded* method of your view:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ViewDidTouch" object:self];
```

Listen for this notification in your view controller. To achieve that add in the view controller's method *viewDidLoad* a line:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onViewDidTouch:) name:@"ViewDidTouch" object:nil];
```

And then implement below method in your view controller:

```
- (void) onViewDidTouch:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple way is to keep a reference to the view controller in `MyView`, e.g., define a property like:

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) MyViewController *viewController;
```

And then in the view controller assign `myView.viewController = self`. This way you can then call whatever methods on the view controller from `MyView`, e.g., `[viewController myView:self changedValue:myValue]` or whatever.

(And, yes, it's possible to add the custom view subclass directly in the storyboard. Just add a generic `UIView` in the storyboard and change its class to `MyView`.)

There are of course many alternative ways, e.g., notifications, or simply polling a property of `MyView` from the view controller if its only of interest at certain times, etc.